# To move an image towards 3 dimensions in android application

Tags: android, 3d, direct3d

I want to move an image in in 3 dimensional way in my android application according to my device movement, for this, I am getting my x y z co-ordinate values through sensorEvent,But I am unable to find APIs to move image in 3 dimesions. Could any one please provide a way(any APIs) to get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the particulars of your application, you could consider using OpenGL ES for manipulations in three dimensions. A quite common approach then would be to render the image onto a 'quad' (basically a flat surface consisting of two triangles) and manipulate that using matrices you construct based on the accelerometer data.

An alternative might be to look into extending the standard ImageView, which out of the box supports manipulations by 3x3 matrices. For rotation this will be sufficient, but obviously you will need an extra dimension for translation - which you're probably after, seen your remark about 'moving' an image.

If you decide to go with the first suggestion, this [example code](http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/) should be quite useful to start with. You'll probably be able to plug your sensor data straight into that and simply add the required math for the matrix manipulations.